# and/or in one word or a phrase

Tags: grammar

Is there a word or a phrase that could be used instead of the cringy "and/or" thing? It looks rather bad in an english paper and I can't come up with a short version of expressing it.

Ex: *There was always a car **and/or** a motorcycle in the parking lot.*

Thanks for all the answers in advance, 
Thomas

Comment: I believe that *There was always a car or a motorcycle in the parking lot* should be quite sufficient to indicate that the parking lot was never empty.

Comment: But I want to indicate not only that, but even that there might have been a car **and** a motorcycle in the lot. Your version of the sentence fails to emphasise that.

Comment: How far do you want to take this? Because there could also be **two cars** in the lot - and technically, *a car and/or a motorcycle* does not cover that. Unless you need to be very precise (e.g. for legal purposes), I would suggest you use ordinary language.

Comment: thanks, you are right... I will have to battle my laziness and write those few extra words.

Answer (score -1):

*I'd suggest that:*
There was always *at least* a car or a motorcycle in the parking lot.

Comment: You might want to include references, otherwise it's more of a helpful comment but an answer.